# Ignore key press while Console Window is not in focus C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, key

I've written a console application which awaits input by the form of key presses. The user however might want to switch applications and doing so disrupts the game since 'Spacebar' is an important key in my application.

I've looked up this topic on StackOverflow and all the prior threads involve either a non-console based application, non-Windows.h libraries, etc.

Currently, my applications getInput() method is essentially this:

```
while (true)
{
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x31))
                {
                    return 1; //User pressed 1 key
                }
                else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x32))
                {
                    return 2; //User pressed 2 key
                }
                else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x33))
                {
                    return 3; //User pressed 3 key
                }
                else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x34))
                {
                    return 4; //User pressed 4 key
                }
                else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x35))
                {
                    return 5; //User pressed 5 key
                }
                else if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x36))
                {
                    return 6; //User pressed 6 key
                }
}
```

How do I get it so that it will ignore inputs made when the console window is not the primary window?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetConsoleWindow` to retrieve the handle of the console output window. Use `GetForegroundWindow` to retrieve the handle of the window the user is currently working with. You can introduce the following boolean, using these two API calls:

```
bool isConsoleWindowFocussed = (GetConsoleWindow() == GetForegroundWindow());
```

and use it in your conditions with a conjunction with the `GetAsyncKeyState`.